# Refering to specific cells of a data frame as input for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am struggling a little with ggplot and my dataframe that I use as input. I have a dataframe `A` that looks like this:

```
   x         y
1  0 50.825022
2  1 44.154257
3  0 50.116500
4  1 46.027000
5  0 55.905105
6  1 50.753209
7  0 44.804500
8  1 42.894000
9  0 15.030799
10 1 11.881330
11 0 21.456833
12 1 18.942833
13 0  5.664676
14 1  3.350577
```

How can I manually refer to specific cells of my data frame and tell ggplot2 that I want to plot, for instance, a point with A[1,1] as my x-value (x=0) and A[1,2] as my y-value (y=50.825002), and then another point with A[2,1] as my x-value (x=1) and A[2,2] as my y-value (y=44.154257), and then link the two points with a line.

The idea is to obtain plots that look like this:
[image]

If someone could hint me the trick with `ggplot2`, I would really appreciate it.

Here is the dataframe to copy and paste if needed:

```
structure(list(x = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
                      0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), y = c(50.8250223621947, 44.1542573925467, 50.1165, 
                                             46.027, 55.9051046135438, 50.753208962261, 44.8045, 42.894, 15.0307991170913, 
                                             11.8813302333097, 21.4568333333333, 18.9428333333333, 5.66467592950172, 
                                             3.35057697360927)), .Names = c("x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                           -14L))
```

Comment: Do you want them all in **one** plot. Or do your want **n** plots with each two points?

Comment: for the labels use: `geom_text()` or `annotate()`. To style the axis google something like "ggplot2 axis ticks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function if you want to provide two points on the fly which would subset those rows and plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_two_points <- function(row1, row2) {
    temp = rbind(df[row1,], df[row2,])
    ggplot(temp, aes(x, y, label = y)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + 
        geom_label(nudge_x = 0.05, nudge_y = 0.15)
}
```

Call the function with which rows you want to display

```
plot_two_points(3, 4)
```

[image]

Comment: I like your solution, thank you! Any idea how I could also add a label with the value of the y next to each point (like in the example figure I posted?).

Comment: @Notna updated the answer with `geom_label`. You can adjust `nudge_x` and `nudge_y` parameter according to your preference.

Comment: When I try your code with the labels and different data frames, I get an error object 'x' not found:

`plot_two_points <- function(df1, df2, df3, row1, row2) {
  temp1 = rbind(df1[row1,], df1[row2,])
  temp2 = rbind(df2[row1,], df2[row2,])
  temp3 = rbind(df3[row1,], df3[row2,])
  ggplot(NULL, aes(x, y, label=y)) + 
    geom_point(data=temp1) +
    geom_line(data=temp1) +
    geom_text() +
    geom_point(data=temp2) + 
    geom_line(data=temp2) +
    geom_text() +
    geom_point(data=temp3) + 
    geom_line(data=temp3) +
    geom_text()
}

plot_two_points(A,B,C,3,4)`

Comment: Actually, nevermind! I forgot to specify the data that I was using in the brackets of `geom_text()`

Answer (score 0):

To simply plot points using `ggplot2` you can use this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(A, aes(factor(x), y)) +
    geom_point()
```

Here we put `x` on x-axis and `y` on y-axis. We are using `factor` as `x` is a categorical variable.

If we need to connect `i` and and `i+1` we have to add grouping variable to data. We can do it with:

```
From 1 to half of the rows repeat integer twice
A$ID <- rep(1:(nrow(A) / 2), each = 2)
# Returns:
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7
```

To add line between the points we can use `geom_path` and specify grouping variable `ID`.

```
ggplot(A, aes(x, y, group = ID)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: very good, but I don't like the use of `factor(x)`. This will lead to confusion if the x values are different from (0,1).

Comment: @AndreElrico Updated my answer